# Single Table Inheritance (STI)... Multi Table Inheritance (MTI)... Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have found MANY posts on these subjects but none have answered my (probably very novice) question.  I am brand new to Rails this month but I have been programming in OOL for a little while.  I think my question might span multiple subjects about Ruby on Rails.  I don't mind reading multiple blogs or tutorials to peace this all together.

I have 4 location models.  Each have a "Name" attribute.

1. Country (has_many :states)
2. State (belongs_to :country has_many :counties has_many :cities, :through => :counties)
3. County (belongs_to :state has_many :cities)
4. City

My end goal is to have an autocomplete textbox for city, county, state.  The user will select a country to narrow down the results.  For example, the user will type in "SA" and the autocomplete textbox will show:

1. Kansas
2. Arkansas
3. Santa Clara County, California
4. San Jose, Santa Clara County, California
5. etc.

So I can easily return the text that I want displayed.  Each model has something like:

> def location_name
>
> // the display name of this model. For example we want the County Model to return "Santa Clara County, California"
>
> "#{name}, #{state.name}"
>
> end

Solutions I tried to research:

1. **Active Record Query Interface** to make one select statement across the multiple tables.  My goal would be to search across multiple models and get a single list of objects with the name containing the search text.
2. **STI** - Maybe create a Location model which all can inherit from but I couldn't find any basic tutorial online that include models with different attributes for each.  Do I "generate" one model with all the fields that all 5 would need then just delete them from the auto generated .rb file?  I assume I will then be able to use Location.where("name like ? and country_id = ?", params[:search], params[:country_id]) and get a full list of all location which fit the search parameters.
3. **MTI** - I looked at this since I'm not a big fan of excess columns in the DB that are mostly blank.  For example :country_id would only be used by states.  So it would be null for all counties and cities, etc.  But all the tutorial seem to imply that STI would be the better way to go.
4. **Polymorphic Associations** - I just started looking into this a few hours ago.  I found something about ":polymorphic => true" and I read another article that talked about a subclass feature.

I have spent quite a few days looking into the "right" way of doing this according to Ruby.  I'd really like to learn and incorporate all that ruby has to offer.  Thanks for any thought!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can watch this video for your further development too.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

one-to-many for your case should be alright i guess..
like this country has many states and the according state has many of cities.

correct me if im wrong @@

Comment: Thanks! I currently have Dynamic Select Menus on my website.  I am hoping to combine the State, County, & City drop down boxes into one autocomplete textbox.

Comment: Nich - Yes similar to this.  The biggest problem that I am having is that no examples out there have searching across multiple Models just as this one is.